# Left out, store bought, Tyson sealed fully cooked chicken patties 20 hours

Tags: chicken

Came in from store but forgot to put up my Tyson fully cooked chicken patties. Never opened, seal not broken, 20 hrs later--do I trash em?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is far outside any kind of safe zone.

**Always always always** throw it out if there's any kind of question.